# Screen Overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm building an app in flutter I've designed the UI and all but it's not responsive once I tilt the screen or change the type of device with device_preview the whole thing becomes a mess. I've checked out a couple of videos on youtube but it doesn't work.
I need help

Comment: add code here, where you are facing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get orientation change by using

1. OrientationBuilder widget, in this widget you will pass 'context' and 'orientation'
   then check orientation == Orientation.portrait for portrait mode and Orientation.landscape for landscape mode and build you UI base upon the check

   OrientationBuilder(
   builder: (context, orientation) {
   return Container(
   child:Text('any text'),
   height:orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 'build portrait ui' : 'build landscape ui';
   },
   );
2. or use MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait for portrait check and vice versa.